# Trying to use NSManagedObjectModel through NSTreeController and NSBrowser

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, binding

I'm trying to use NSManagedObjectModel through NSTreeController and NSBrowser. I found some simple tutorials on the Net but they don't solve all my problems. Right now I can: add nodes (except in the leaf); to show children's nodes selecting the parent. My model is heterogeneous, all entities are different, but have the same properties: "name"; "children" (except the leaf); "parent (except the root). My model is all generated by the XCode. I don't have entered any code and don't have changed anything, all is generated by the XCode and Interface Builder.

I have 3 questions:
(1) How can I avoid the "children key error" when I reach the leaf entity?
(2) How can I avoid the creation of a children in the column of a parent?
(3) How can I disable the add children button if no one parent is selected?

(Thanks about some help. :D )

Answer (score 1):

With regard to question 1: I have all my nodes implement all methods, but the `leaf` entities return nil for the `children` getter method, for example, and the root returns nil for `parent`.

Unfortunately, I haven't used `NSBrowser`, I use this technique for `NSOutlineView` and `NSTreeController`, so I can't help with questions 2 & 3.